# React Native Expo Live chat functions

Tags: react-native, expo, livechat

Are there any free/cheap react native customer help desk widgets or functions? I tried to look into intercom but it is not supported in expo.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial config plugin that can be used with expo for the official Intercom React Native library, here: https://github.com/cmaycumber/with-rn-intercom